# Magento 2 Issues after Migration

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration-tool

I have successfully migrated all data with data-migration-tool from Magento 1.9.1.0 to Magento 2.2.4.

When trying to create customer from backend it gives below error

**`No such entity with email = xxx@abc.com, websiteId = 1`**

While when going to Back-end and trying to add new customer from admin->customers->add new customer

and trying to select website from option **Associate to Website** ,it is grayed out(refer image),not clickable.

I have multiple websites and stores.

[image]

Please Help to resolve this issue.

I have searched on forum and found some useful links but they are not helpfull for me.

I have run query and reindex all data but not any succes

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

While when trying to create customer programatically then it is creating successfully.